# Why will my python built exe program with appJar and Cxfreeze works automatically on some computer?

Tags: python, user-interface, computer-vision, cx-freeze, huawei-mobile-services

I'm using python 2.7.
I created a small program with appJar to create the user interface and packed it with Cx_freeze. It works fine on my computer and several other Thinkpads. But it acted strangely on several Huawei Magicbook(not everyone).All of those computers are using Windows 10. After I start the program on those computer, first the size doesn't appear correctly, and also some of the width setting appear differently.

This is my code of the UI size part, on some computer it looks smaller than "1000x600":

```
app=gui("Config Compare", "1000x600")
app.setResizable(canResize=False)
```

That's not the only problem, there are many buttons and checkboxes on the interface linked with a Textarea, the Textarea kept printing stuffs, it seems like, those buttons and checkboxes clicked themselves. I haven't touch anything, but it seems like something has went through every button on my interface again and again until I close the program.

Why will such thing happen?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)